# How to use Fubini's theorem for an area when function is of only one variable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fubini-tonelli-theorems

[image]

In finding the the area of the equation $f(x,y) = cos(x)$ inside the bounded area above using Fubini's theorem, why is the equation $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\sin(x)}^{\sin(x)+1} 1 \,dy \,dx$ and not $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\sin(x)}^{\sin(x)+1} \cos(x) \,dy \,dx$?

Comment: Also, how do I embed LaTeX in my question? This is my first time asking.

Comment: Use the \$\$ signs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I submitted an edit embedding the picture, since new users can't do that.

Comment: Why do you assume that the first one is correct?